# .htaccess to remove string but not redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I am sure this already exists, but I'm not too sure the terminology to search for exactly what I am looking for.

I have a url like http://www.example.com/members/$variable/achievements and I want all of these page to redirect to one level up, for example http://www.example.com/members/$variable.

I was originally using :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^members/([\w]*)/achievements/$ http://www.example.com  [R=301,L]
```

which works fine for redirecting the original page to the homepage, but I would rather it go to that variable page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^members/([^/]+)/achievements/?$ http://www.example.com/members/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This assumes there is something after `$variable/achievements` (with and without the ending `/`) and redirect it back to `http://www.example.com/members/$variable/`

Comment: Close, and I guess I left out 2 key pieces.  1) The achievements part should be specific.  There might be other things such as members/$variable/profile which I don't want to redirect.  I only want the achievements one to redirect  2) The returned URL should end with / so http://www.example.com/members/$variable/

Comment: See update, does it have anything past `achievements`? or just the `/` at best.